# MPI allReduce iteration

Tags: c, matrix, mpi

I have a problem with the use of the MPI_allReduce, I have to update the matrices R_T, R_T_original after each iteration because the matrix R_T is the same in every processes but the matrices mid_L, mid_B, mid_A are different for each processes. In my example the matrices A,B,L have 3 rows, I have 3 processes and each of them have one row of matrix(A,L,B), the variable no zero has 3 different values (P0-->no zero=2,P1-->nozero=2,P2--> nozero=3), in my debug output I recive the result until i=1 and the program goes to indetermiante phase. I think that the process P2 has to calculate the iteration i=2 yet while the processes P0 and P1 already have terminate the iteration i. How can I fix this problem?

```
double sub = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<no_zero; i++){
      sub=alpha2*(mid_A[rows_nz[i]][cols_nz[i]]-mid_B[rows_nz[i]][cols_nz[i]]);

    for(int k=0; k<nF;k++){
        mid_L[rows_nz[i]][k] = mid_L[rows_nz[i]][k]-sub*(-R_T_original[cols_nz[i]][k]);


    MPI_Allreduce(&R_T[0][0], &appo[0][0], nI*nF, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


        matrixcopy(R_T, appo, nI, nF);

        R_T[cols_nz[i]][k] = R_T[cols_nz[i]][k]-sub*(-mid_L_original[rows_nz[i]][k]);


    }
}



 // Clone matrix
 matrixcopy(mid_L_original, mid_L, dim_L, nF);
 matrixcopy(R_T_original, R_T, nI, nF);
```

}

Comment: What is `R_T[0][0]` the first time it is sent as an argument here; `MPI_Allreduce(&R_T[0][0], ...` ? (It does not look like a buffer, rather a single element.)

Comment: Please edit your question with a [MCVE], it is virtually impossible to help with such a small snippet, especially not knowing how your buffers are declared and allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Using collective MPI operations can be tricky sometimes. You are calling `MPI_Allreduce` in a loop, but because the value of `non_zero` differs from rank to rank, not all ranks make the same number of calls to `MPI_Allreduce`. When P2 is doing iteration `i = 2`, it calls `MPI_Allreduce` in the inner loop and that blocks forever waiting for P0 and P1 to make the same all-reduce call, which they won't, because the loop has one less iteration in those ranks.

In order for an MPI program to be a correct one with respect to collective operations such as `MPI_Allreduce`, each rank in the communicators involved must call the same collective operations the same number of times and in the same order.

You need to rethink your algorithm and equalise the number of calls to `MPI_Allreduce` in all ranks or to better explain what mathematical computation you are trying to achieve.